# Set SameSite=strict for session cookies

Tags: 9, cookies

I'm trying to figure out how to set the SameSite cookie attribute for Drupal 8 session cookies, but I can't find a solution.

I thought SessionConfiguration might give me enough options, but it seems not.

Where can I perform such magic?

Comment: Have you managed to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Check this issue https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3150614
You could set the following configuration in services.yml

```
parameters:
  session.storage.options:
    cookie_samesite: strict
```

Comment: That's for D9 not D8

Comment: I tried this on Drupal Core 9.3.0, still doesn't work for me.

Comment: I actually think that should work. Did you rebuild the container after setting that?

Comment: The linked issue hasn't been marked as fixed, yet. That means the changes it introduces haven't been committed.

Comment: That is not true—it should work. The changes in the issue only document this hidden feature.

Comment: This code is taken from my project and it works. Linked issue just add description and tests. Check Drupal\Core\Session\SessionConfiguration and you will find that options are passed as is.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but maybe still of use to someone.

In an environment where you can't control `services.yml`, e.g. because your organisation/client doesn't let you edit it (for security/compliance reasons for example) and if `ini_set('session.cookie_samesite', 'strict')` is not an option for you (PHP > 7.3 according to https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.security.ini.php), you can use a session decorator.

You need a service definition, e.g. `my_modules.services.yml`

```
services:
  my_module.session_configuration:
    class: Drupal\my_module\Session\SessionConfiguration
    decorates: session_configuration
    decoration_priority: 9
    public: false
    arguments: ['@my_module.session_configuration.inner']
```

And the actual class, e.g. `my_module\src\Session\SessionConfiguration.php`:

```
namespace Drupal\my_module\Session;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Drupal\Core\Session\SessionConfigurationInterface;

class SessionConfiguration implements SessionConfigurationInterface {

  /**
   * Original service object.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\core\Session\SessionConfigurationInterface
   */
  protected $sessionConfiguration;

  /**
   * Constructs a new Session Configuration instance.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\core\Session\SessionConfigurationInterface $session_configuration
   *   The original session configuration service.
   */
  public function __construct(SessionConfigurationInterface $session_configuration) {
    $this->sessionConfiguration = $session_configuration;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function hasSession(Request $request) {
    return $this->sessionConfiguration->hasSession($request);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getOptions(Request $request) {
    $options = $this->sessionConfiguration->getOptions($request);
    $options['cookie_samesite'] = 'Strict';
    return $options;
  }
}
```

I saw variations of this decorator pattern in different examples on the web, sometimes [extending the base service](https://www.axelerant.com/blog/drupal-8-service-decorators) and sometimes [implementing the appropriate interface](https://www.blueoakinteractive.com/blog/service-decorators-drupal-8) instead. There is a good discussion about this here: https://www.phase2technology.com/blog/using-symfony-service-decorators-drupal-8

Comment: I don't think you need all of this.

Comment: @cilefen And that's the downvote for?

Comment: @cilefen While I agree that the accepted answer solves this in an environment that you control completely, my answer provides a work-around when your organisation or client doesn't let you modify `services.yml`, e.g. for security/compliance reasons.

Comment: The answer doesn't explain that is the reason for the larger implementation.

Comment: @cilefen Ok, I added it. Makes sense. But seriously downvoting for that reason? Leave a comment and be good!